# iOS - How to know if iCloud photo transfer ability is enabled

Tags: iphone, image, settings, ios5, icloud

The new iCloud service has many possible configurations. How may I know if the device of my user is configured to send taken pictures to an iCloud server instead of storing them just on the device ?

Comment: are you talking about Photo Stream or are you talking about iCloud backups?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann : I'm talking about photos stream, but reading your comment, I'm talking about any mean that may send the iPhone photos to the iCloud in a readable way, so I guess backups are in that scope.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if iCloud is activated you could simply call:

```
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];   
 NSURL *cloudURL = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];   
 if (cloudURL != nil) {   
    // iCloud is available
 }
```

This can give you a hint if iCloud is available at all. If you want to use iCloud to store pictures you can build your own stuff. I'm not really sure what you are planning to do.

Comment: I just want to display a notice if the pictures taken with my app are going to be stored on the iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you give a valid ubiquity container identifier below method should return `YES`:

```
static NSString *UbiquityContainerIdentifier = @"ABCDEFGHI0.com.acme.MyApp";

- (BOOL) iCloudIsAvailable
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *ubiquityURL = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:UbiquityContainerIdentifier];
    return (ubiquityURL) ? YES : NO;
}
```

However, I've found that calling `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:` might take time (several seconds) the very first time within a session. So, just make sure you call this in the background to not block the UI temporarily:

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue,^{
    BOOL isAvailable = [self iCloudIsAvailable]
    /* change to the main queue if you want to do something with the UI. For example: */
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        if (!isAvailable){
            /* inform the user */
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init...]
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
    });
});
```