# iOS - Prevent pictures taken with the camera to go to the iCloud

Tags: iphone, camera, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller, icloud

Is there a way to prevent any picture taken with the UIImagePickerController and saved to the Camera roll to go to the iCloud. In any case.

This question is also linked with this one from myself : [iOS - How to know if iCloud photo transfer ability is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020836/ios-how-to-know-if-icloud-photo-transfer-ability-is-enabled)

Comment: Is this not a question for SuperUser rather than SO?

Answer (score 1):

No. Your app has no control over what happens to images saved to the Camera Roll—and nor should it.