# iCloud - Photo Stream

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, icloud, icloud-api

Is there any public API which will tell me if a user has iCloud's Photo Stream feature enabled on the device?

I wish to perform some actions based on the result of this call, so it is essential that I can detect if it is enabled.

Comment: [Your question has been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020836/ios-how-to-know-if-icloud-photo-transfer-ability-is-enabled) (but hasn't been answered yet). My gut feeling is that there isn't an API for this; consider filing a [bug with Apple](http://bugreporter.apple.com).

Answer (score 0):

It would appear not, although I am sure I am not the only person who would find this useful.